# I keep getting a 404 error when django is looking for static files

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, static-files

I keep getting a 404 error when django is looking for static files.

**settings.py**

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'business', 'static_cdn')
STATIC_URL = '/static_cdn/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'business', 'static'),
]
```

**project tree structure of app**

```
- business
-- migrations
--- ....
-- static_cdn
--- business
---- main.css
---- scripts.js
-- templates
--- business
---- base.html
---- home.html
-- templatetags
--- ...
-- __init__.py
-- admin.py
-- apps.py
-- models.py
-- tests.py
-- urls.py
-- views.py
```

**Error**

```
[29/Jul/2019 13:09:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12670
[29/Jul/2019 13:09:45] "GET /static_cdn/business/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 77
[29/Jul/2019 13:09:45] "GET /static_cdn/business/scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 404 77
```

I also link to static files like `{% static 'business/main.css' %}` and I do have `{% load static %}` at the top of my document.

Why isn't django able to find the static files? The error says it is looking in the correct place but it is returning 404 error.

If you need anything else, you can look at my [code](https://github.com/PRREMIA/prremia-django)

**Note:**
I think that django isn't able to ***read*** this files but I don't know why... Collectstatic puts all `static_cdn/` into `static/` in same app dir.

Comment: By any chance DEBUG is set to False?

Comment: @Amit Yes it is

Comment: Try changing it to True only if you are in development environment and not production.

Comment: @Amit I'm trying to push it to heroku, and the exact same things will happen there as well, right?

Comment: For production you might have to run collectstatic first. If you are pushing for production, never set DEBUG to True. Please see Dango documentation carefully for deployment. It is not very hard but not trivial either. Be careful. For the time being for testing "locally" set DEBUG to True. All the best.

Comment: @Amit So, oops. It worked! But how would I make this work in production

Comment: Do collectstatic first and set DEBUG to FALSE. put your static directory where it is safe. Not advisable to put in the root folder of code. Other small but important details. I would have gone through Heroku docs carefully. Glad that it worked out for you.

Comment: @Amit Wait.... Slow down. Collectstatic is already done. Do I just push to heroku. (Heroku's settings is False)? Also, I put this static dir in my app dir.

Comment: @Amit also, please answer so I can accept it. (If i forget that I already asked this, I can just look at the answer. comments are frustrating) :D :)

Comment: I am sorry. Unfortunately I don't have experience with Heroku. So I can not advise other than seeing documentation. Sorry.

Comment: I have given the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have set DEBUG to False. If and only if, you are in development environment , set DEBUG to True. If you are planning for production, do collectstatic first and do appropriate changes in the settings.py and set DEBUG back to False. See the Django doc and your production server doc. Also don't forget to restart the server.
Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have defined BASE_DIR as below

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

which means it is pointing to the root folder while your **static_cdn** folder is lying under **business** folder

While defining below, you will have to update path to one within business folder for **STATIC_ROOT** and **STATICFILES_DIRS**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn')
STATIC_URL = '/static_cdn/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn'),
]
```

as below

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'business', 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static_cdn/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'business', 'static_cdn'),
]
```

Comment: Yes, but STATICFILES_DIRS cannot be the same as STATIC_ROOT

Comment: That is just for reference. In your case change STATIC_ROOT to something you will use in production after using command "collectstatic". For example - STATIC_ROOT can be set to "static" while rest can point to "static_cdn". In that case, when collectstatic command is executed, all resources will be copied to "static" folder.

Comment: Oh, well, yeah. I already did that! I knew exactly what you were going to say :D

Answer (score 0):

Rename your static folder to static_cdn and update settings.py

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn')
STATIC_URL = '/static_cdn/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn'),
]
```

i.e. this structure:

**project tree structure of app**

```
- business
-- migrations
--- ....
-- static_cdn
--- business
---- main.css
---- scripts.js
-- templates
--- business
---- base.html
---- home.html
-- templatetags
--- ...
-- __init__.py
-- admin.py
-- apps.py
-- models.py
-- tests.py
-- urls.py
-- views.py
```

Comment: I had tried this, right after asking this question. It didn't work :(

Comment: @12944qwerty did you also change settings.py to make use of static_cdn and not static ? Updated the answer.

Comment: Oh, I just realized a mistake. It's `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static_cdn')` which means that I can't make STATIC_DIRS include this.